# How to get the variable from another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What should I write in another JavaScript file if I want to get the the value of name?

Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
    return {
        name : 'blabla'
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.name = UserService.name;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`UserService` is an angular service, so to access it, you need to inject it in inside of what you want, be it a `directive`, another `service`, `controller`, etc. You can't access it outside of angular realm.

Heres how you can access it inside a sample directive

```
//need to add myApp module as a dependency
angular.module('sampleModule',['myApp'])
   //inject it here
   .directive('sampleDirective',['UserService',function(UserService){
        return {
             scope:{},
             restrict:'E',
             link:function(scope, elem, attr){
                   // access UserService here
                    console.log(UserService.name);
             }
      }

}])
.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will check it too.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by another JavaScript file? The value of name is returned in "UserService", if you wish to access that same name in another part of your application e.g another controller/directive then you must inject that service("UserService").